# C# string format best overloaded method match error

Tags: c#, string, formatting

I am completely unfamiliar to C#, so bear with me.

```
private static string GetFormattedValue(string dataType, dynamic cellValue)
    {
        string formattedCellValue = string.Empty;
        if (cellValue == null)
            cellValue = DBNull.Value;

        if (dataType == "STRING")
        {
            formattedCellValue = string.Format("'{0}',", cellValue);
        }
        else if (dataType == "NUMBER")
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(cellValue)))
                cellValue = 0;
            formattedCellValue = string.Format("'{0}',", cellValue.ToString("F17"));
        }
        else if (dataType == "DATE")
        {
            formattedCellValue = string.Format("'{0}',", cellValue);
        }
        else
        {
            formattedCellValue = string.Format("'{0}',", cellValue.ToString("F17"));
        }

        return formattedCellValue;
```

when `dataType` is NUMBER and `cellValue` is a whole number, i get an error stating:
    "the best overloaded method match for string.ToString(System.IFormatProvider) has some invalid arguments"

`cellValue` will often be extremely small numbers that, without the "F17", will be returned as scientific notation (which causes another error down the line), but also whole numbers which cause the error above.

this is not my code, i'm just running it and know just about enough to step through it.  any ideas how to determine if `cellValue` can be read to determine if a whole number or not?  or any other better suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous methods that tries to parse a string to a number, such as [Double.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/994c0zb1.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

F17 references a Double data type... not a string.

try this and let me know:

```
        else if (dataType == "NUMBER")
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(cellValue)))
                cellValue = 0;
            formattedCellValue = string.Format("'{0}',", Convert.ToDouble(Convert.ToString(cellValue)).ToString("F17"));
        }
```